# Windows File Sharing over Switch connected to multiple Gateways

Tags: windows-10, networking, file-sharing, usb-storage

The title might seems confusing, kindly suggest an edit if you have a better one.

Here is the current setup.

[image: Here is the current setup]

Question 1: All computers are using Windows 10, can i use File Sharing to all three computers even with different Gateway?

Question 2: Can I hook up an AP with external drive to the Switch that will act as a File Server while each computer is connected to either modem?

Comment: whats the subnet of the computers (subnet mask)?

Answer (score 1):

Gateways are used for communications *between* networks (subnets), not within a network. If every computer thinks it's in the same subnet as the other computers (e.g. the 255.255.255.0 netmasks tell them that they're in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet), then gateways are irrelevant – the computers will not *use* a gateway to send packets to another device that's on the same subnet; they will send packets directly to each other across the switch.